# Natural gas smell in house after new roof installation

Tags: roofing, smell, natural-gas

We just had our roof replaced today, and I've noticed a distinct smell of natural gas at random times while walking through the house. When they were here they had large pieces of wood up against the garage to protect it and I noticed the garage reaked of the smell after they left. So I opened the garage to let it air out, and now it's fine. But I still have random smells theoughout the house that smells like natural gas (we do have a gas range and water heater).

Is this normal, after replacing our gas vent? Could this be something else that just smells like gas?

Fwiw, I have two young daughters in the house  - kind of worried to go to sleep without figuring this out first.

Comment: Is the pilot light out on your WH? Why would the garage have a gas leak in it? Is that where your WH is, or the gas meter? Where are both of those anyway? If it is the WH's pilot light, you should probably inspect the flue for obstructions. Personally, *I* would sleep better if you'd go turn off the valve on your gas meter until this is sorted (line up the two holes where they'd put a lock on it, usually that's a 90 degree turn).

Comment: [What To Do If You Smell Gas](http://www.safebee.com/home/what-do-if-you-smell-gas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in ANY doubt about whether there is a significant gas leak, evacuate, alert the fire department, and tell the gas company to send someone over with a sniffer to check for gas and find the source if a leak does exist.

However, remember that there might just be a skunk in the area...

If you're using gas, it's probably worth investing in a gas alarm before this issue arises. Some serve as carbon monoxide alarms too.

(I heat with gas, have cooked on a gas range (the only option I like more is inductive, and that's a bit of a mixed bag), and will probably switch to a gas dryer when I upgrade the laundry, so I'm certainly not particularly afraid of it. But like electricity it should be treated with respect, and if it seems to be appearing someplace it shouldn't, you want someone who knows what they are doing to investigate.)

Comment: For those who may travel here in the future -- **It was a gas leak!**. The roofing company must have pierced an auxiliary gas line in our attic. Public Utilities Company came out at 12:30am, tested, and shut off the gas to the house.